# Returning arguments from Java and Python

Tags: java, python, python-3.x

Imagine I have script `real.java` which has to pass arguments `A`, `B` and `C` to a python script `code.py`. Then, `code.py` does something and have to return arguments `fi` and `foo` to `real.java`. But I do not know how to do create that function in java neither in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ProcessBuilder or you can use something like jython.

ProcessBuilder example: [How to return value from Python script to Java using ProcessBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55388121/how-to-return-value-from-python-script-to-java-using-processbuilder)
Jython Documentation: https://www.jython.org/